# Node app, perfectly valid JSON, how is "d" not defined?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, webrtc, easyrtc

I'm trying to run the EasyRTC default server code and examples.

If you look at the Node console you can see the JSON string returned in "body". Then immediately after, I get an error that "d" is not defined. The JSON is valid so how can this be?

Thanks for taking a look. I really need your advice.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So as per usual, about 5 minutes after posting here, the answer comes to me...

```
body = JSON.parse(body)
```

Comment: To be clear to anyone reading, the `body` is a string when passed through the argument so you need to parse it as a valid JSON object.

Comment: Just so. Thanks Jake :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log("typeof body=", typeof body);
```

Returns "object" or "string" ?
It must be a string so you must JSON.parse it first.